# How to pass a GENERIC @Published property in ObservableObject viewModel to a view?

Tags: generics, swiftui, swift-protocols, swiftui-list

How to pass a generic @Published property in ObservableObject viewModel to a view? Can a generic variable be observed by @Published?

Declaration of protocol:

```
protocol SectionHeaderViewObject {
         var name: String
         var iconName: String
         ...
    }
```

I leave out the implementation of SectionHeaderViewGenerator by customObject1 and customObject2.
Here is the viewModel and the headerView.

```
struct ListViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var sections: [customObject1 : [Int]] = [:]

   enum Sort {
      case customObject1, customObject2
   }

   var sort: Sort {
      didSet {
          switch self {
              case .customObject1:
                        sections = [CustomObject1():[1]]
              case .customObject2:
                        sections = [CustomObject2():[1]]
          }
       }
   }
}

struct SectionHeaderView<T: SectionHeaderViewGenerator> {
    var customObject: T
    var body: some View {
         HStack {
            Text(customObject.name)
            Image(customObject.iconName)
    }
}
```

Call by the view:

```
struct ListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ListViewModel
    var body: some View {
        List {
           Section(header: SectionHeaderView(customObject: viewModel.customObject) {
                  aRowView()
             }
        }

}
```

I want to make something like this. But I am having problem to implement generics to the keys of `sections` dictionary.

```
@Published var sections: [SectionHeaderViewObject : Int] = [:]
```

in effect, by combining:

```
@Published var sections: [customObject1 : Int] = [:]
@Published var sections: [customObject2 : Int] = [:]
```

Comment: Would you make provided snapshot compilable?

Comment: I have edited above to point out the problem. I don't know how can I apply generics to pass through both types in the same variable.